# Take picture then load in ImageView not always working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using code the from the examples [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

My issue is that **sometimes** the image doesn't load into the ImageView. I've just noticed this behavior recently. I've found that if I debug through the code it works 100% of the time.

My assumption is that the image file sometimes doesn't get created in time to be usable in the `onActivityResult`. Has anyone run into this issue? Suggestions on how to compensate?

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code up? Kind of tough to know what might be causing the issue without it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is mobile processing speed issue! can't tell exactly but i Tried it in this way, and it work like charm always!

```
public class LaunchCamera extends Activity {
 ImageView imVCature_pic;
 Button btnCapture;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_camera);
  initializeControls();
 }

 private void initializeControls() {
  imVCature_pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imVCature_pic);
  btnCapture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
  btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    /* create an instance of intent
     * pass action android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE 
     * as argument to launch camera
     */
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    /*create instance of File with name img.jpg*/
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "img.jpg");
    /*put uri as extra in intent object*/
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    /*start activity for result pass intent as argument and request code */
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   }
  });

 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  //if request code is same we pass as argument in startActivityForResult
  if(requestCode==1){
   //create instance of File with same name we created before to get image from storage
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "img.jpg");
   //get bitmap from path with size of
   imVCature_pic.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 600, 450));
   }
 }
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
   int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { 
  // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
  final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  //Query bitmap without allocating memory
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  //decode file from path
  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
  // Calculate inSampleSize
  // Raw height and width of image
  final int height = options.outHeight;
  final int width = options.outWidth;
  //decode according to configuration or according best match
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
  int inSampleSize = 1;
  if (height > reqHeight) {
   inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
  }
  int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;
  if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
   //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
   inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
  }
  //if value is greater than 1,sub sample the original image
  options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
  // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
  return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
 }
}
```

**I have taken reference from** [this](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/capture-images-using-intent-android.html) and [this](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/capture-images-and-crop-images-using.html).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it. I can't get the issue to appear anymore so I may have inadvertently fixed it, but my phone also just got an update so it's hard to tell what was going on. Enjoy the bounty :)